# Twilio StatusCallback "To"

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

When I obtain the StatusCallback in my app. I see that the field “To” is empty. I am using Twilio JS Client SDK to initialize the call. How do I set the field of “To” to be the client ID that I am calling to?

So far, my twilio TwiML function is set up as such:

```
function voiceResponse(event) {
  // Create a TwiML voice response
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

  if(event.To) {
    // Wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
    // if is a valid phone number
    const attr = isAValidPhoneNumber(event.To) ? 'number' : 'client';

    const dial = twiml.dial({
      callerId: event.From,
      answerOnBridge: "true"              // answerOnBridge starts the duration when both parties are connected, but might be 1-2s off during connectivity
    });
    dial[attr]({
      statusCallbackEvent: 'completed',
      statusCallback: 'https://aaaa.com/statuscallback',
      statusCallbackMethod: 'POST'
    }, event.To);
  } else {
    twiml.say('Thanks for calling!');
  }

  return twiml.toString();
}
```

```
function tokenGenerator(user_uid, match_uid) {
  const capability = new ClientCapability({
    accountSid: config.accountSid,
    authToken: config.authToken,
// time that the token is alive, call does NOT terminate if token expired, time in seconds, 24hr max
    ttl: 60
  });

  capability.addScope(new ClientCapability.IncomingClientScope(user_uid));
  capability.addScope(new ClientCapability.OutgoingClientScope({
    applicationSid: config.twimlAppSid,
    clientName: user_uid,
  }));

  return {
    identity: user_uid,
    token: capability.toJwt(),
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The To is not populated for the Twilio Client SDK since the To is Twilio. This is considered the "parent" leg of the call. You need to look at the TwiML you are telling Twilio to execute on behalf of the client (via the Application SID you provided as part of the Access Token), to see where the other leg, the "child", leg is going to.

Comment: Ok, what you are saying is that I should define the `To` parameter when defining the TwiML token? In that case, how should I do that exactly? Thanks

Comment: No, you can't define the To for the Twilio Client, the To is ultimately the destination you are sending the call to when the user enters the number in the client (usually), you pass that parameter into the Voice URL as a parameter (the Voice URL is defined in your Application SID) which tells Twilio what number to dial.

Comment: I can edit the `from` parameter of the statuscallback with `callerId: event.From,`, but why not the To using the same way?

Comment: Why doesn't it work the way you want it to work? As stated above, the To from a Twilio client is `To` Twilio. Once Twilio get the request from the Twilio Client, Twilio is told by your application where to ultimately deliver the call, which is another unique CallSID, and then connects the two calls.

Comment: Example 4: Call forwarding with Twilio Client or Mobile SDK - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132367-How-Much-am-I-Charged-for-Call-Forwarding-with-Twilio-